# MPI sends that "can't be buffered by the network"

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I was following a tutorial on http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/point-to-point-communication-application-random-walk/
and there is a sentence that says " **If the sends eventually can’t be buffered by the network**, they will block until a matching receive is posted."

When is `MPI_SEND()` not able to be buffered by a network?

I would guess this question has been asked before but I honestly don't know what keywords to search for here.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, it depends.

Longer story, it depends on your MPI library, the message size, the interconnect being used, how many messages have been buffered before, the tuning options you are using, and other factors.

Keep it mind a program that assumes `MPI_Send()` will return if no matching receive has been posted is incorrect with respect to the MPI standard.

Another way to put it is a correct MPI program will not deadlock if you replace all `MPI_Send()` with `MPI_Ssend()`.

Comment: Thanks. Does your last sentence imply that we should strive to use MPI_Ssend send of MPI_Send?

Comment: In production, you should use `MPI_Send()` unless you have a good reason to use `MPI_Ssend()`. That being said, it can be a good practice to use `MPI_Ssend()` (or force `MPI_Send()` to block until a receive is posted via some tuning parameters) and check the code does not hang before releasing it.